# Why I have 2 version PHP inside my computer?

Tags: php, xampp, duplicates

I have a problem with my current PHP version.

When I open cmd and first check of my php version :

```
C:\Users\me>php -v
PHP 5.3.24 <cli> ..... (and so on)
```

but, when I move my current location of prompt to inside xampp/php folder, it looks like this :

```
C:\xampp\php>php -v
PHP 5.5.9 <cli> ..... (and so on)
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem.

Comment: Are you using other packages like Xampp? for example, wamp? Also, have you installed php on the computer too?

Comment: Check out the path in command line. I guess there will be the location of first PHP installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have two installations of PHP on your computer. 5.5.9 is the version of your php installation in `C:\xampp\php`. The other version (5.3.24) must be installed somewhere else on your computer and is probably registered as Path variable, that's why you can call that php file from any location.

Check your Path variable in your environment variables for an entry pointing to another php-installation.

Comment: thanks, i've found another PHP is belong to IIS Express. What should i do with IIS, i think it is belong to my windows. Am i need to uninstall IIS or i just remove it from path ?

Comment: I don't see the problem with having multiple PHP installations (I have it too). The only problem might be, if you need to run PHP form cmd, then you should edit the path variable as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple, You had installed 2 version in your of PHP. One you install is by normal way like

```
 sudo apt-get install php-5
```

and then you tried to install Xampp. whenever you start Xampp server you will get access to other version. To use 5.3 version you will need to install separate package of Apache and MySql.

[Learn more here](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)